# Can't style my DIV with Magnific popup and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, magnific-popup

I'm using PHP/SQL to display my elements. I added the plugin [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to light boxed the elements when the user click on it.

However I can't style my poping up element because I use the #ID (Which is supposed to be the one to style the popup) to select the clicked element.

Is there any other way to display my elements so I can style my popups?

Here is my code :

**PHP / HTML**

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>

  <div class="grid-item">

   <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog-<?php echo $row['leakID']?>" >
   <img src="<?php echo $row['leakURL']?>">
   </a>

 </div>

 // The hidden POP-UP
 <div id="small-dialog-<?php echo $row['leakID']?>" class="mfp-hide">
   <img src="<?php echo $row['leakURL']?>">
</div>

<?php endwhile?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
type: 'inline',

fixedContentPos: false,
fixedBgPos: true,

overflowY: 'auto',

closeBtnInside: true,
preloader: false,

midClick: true,
removalDelay: 300,
mainClass: 'my-mfp-slide-bottom'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mfp class to style the contents of the popup....

```
.mfp-container div[id^=small-dialog-] {
    style here...
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Where do I add the .mfp-container in the html?

Comment: The `.mfp-container` is the class used by magnific popup that wraps the content. Add the above to your stylesheet or on the page with your popups inbetween `<style></style>` tags.